# backbone.js collection sync with server

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out how to make a backbone.js Collection stay synchronized with a server at the end of an url.

I would like to be able to add a model to a collection and have the collection automatically do a POST with the new model to the collection url...

I cant seam to find the functionality for this anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Models are never saved to the collection endpoint, they have their own url property to configure where they are saved.

Instead of calling `add` on the collection then `save` on the model, you can just call `create` on the collection and it'll do both, but you must configure the model's URL.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/some/path'
});
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/some/path',
    model: MyModel
});

var instance = new MyCollection();
instance.fetch(); //fetches at /some/path

// ...

instance.create({ foo: 'bar' }); // adds to collection and saves the new model
```

### [Documentation for create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

> In order for this to work, you should set the model property of the
>   collection.